# Android save the entire state Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, instance

I’m developing a game, and when the user is playing and blocks the cellphone or change to another app and a long time passes, my app when you bring it to front it starts again.

I want to continue from the moment he pauses the game. I read about onSaveInstanceSate and all of that, but I only see you can save values one by one. In my activity I have like 150 things to save with that solution.
Is not a way to save the entire Activity in an easier option? I Cant’t save 150 values.

Comment: "Can't save 150 values"?
You most certainly can.  But, you shouldn't have to.  You shouldn't have 150 values just floating around independently in a single class.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html

Comment: Of course i cant. But its a very hard work. Must be a way to bring the same state when i pause it. I have that number, have a lot of information in that activity. Have objects, have views, have a lot of things.

Comment: @cricket_007 i read about that. The game changes de values of variables and objects, every time it changes i have to save all? How can i know when the activity is going to start again?

Comment: Thats up to the OS. You can tell via `onPause()` and `onStart()` methods of an Activity, and thats where you save and restore state

Answer (score 0):

Could you break the 150 values into smaller objects? Using a library such as [Icepick](https://github.com/frankiesardo/icepick) would make for cleaner code.

Comment: i have class objects and all of that. But you can not save objects in onSaveInstanceSate wright?

Comment: Hi you can save objects if you have them extend Parcelable for Serializable. Refer to this link to learn how to store these classes. http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/